# Long and full of math titles

Tags: discussion, titles

Is it right to have titles long and full of math, spanning on more than two lines, like this

[Voyager mission polynomials. Prove that for any $p(x)$ $|p(x)(1+x+x^3+x^4+x^6)|+|p(x)(1+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)|\geq10$, where $|\cdot|$  number of monoms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177465/voyager-mission-polynomials-prove-that-for-any-px-px1xx3x4x6) ,

or it should be suggested to the OP to make the title shorter, or lastly we should edit the title without asking the OP?

Comment: The "informative-ness" of a title is a certainly more important criterion than length, but one can try for brevity alongside clarity in the titles...